# Traffic monitoring tools for VMWare Server?

Tags: vmware-server, traffic-measurement

We want to monitor traffic usage for each of our virtual machines - we need to generate a monthly traffic report (in terms of bytes, for billing purposes).

How can we do this?

Our platform is VMWare Server 2, using bridged interfaces on Windows Server 2003

thanks,

ashley

Comment: What is your virtualisation platform? E.g. VMWare is quite good with graphs:
http://www.vmware.com/support/vc11/doc/c16perftab.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it yet, but there is a Linux app [vnStat](http://humdi.net/vnstat/) which may be what you are looking for.

There is [vMonitor](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/va/125883) for windows but I have never tried it.
Are you using bridged interfaces? Are you running vmware server on Linux?

Comment: Thanks Sean. We are using bridged interfaces on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Perhaps try vMonitor, I haven't used it yet so can't say if it will work for your platform. http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/va/125883